# Slow performance when wrapping BufferedReader in custom FilterReader

Tags: java, performance, io

While tinkering around with some I/O stuff, I made an interesting observation: my custom FilterReader seemed to have some unexpected performance overhead. To try and diagnose the issue, I threw together a simple performance test:

```
import java.io.*;

abstract class Test
{
    public final long timeRun(Reader in) throws IOException
    {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        run(in);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        return end - start;
    }

    protected abstract void run(Reader in) throws IOException;
}

class WrapInFilterTest extends Test
{
    private class LetterFilterReader extends FilterReader
    {
        public LetterFilterReader(Reader in)
        {
            super(in);
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read()) != -1)
            {
                if (Character.isLetter(read))
                    break;
            }
            return read;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(Reader in) throws IOException
    {
        try (Reader letterReader = new LetterFilterReader(in))
        {
            while (letterReader.read() != -1);
        }
    }
}

class RawReaderTest extends Test
{
    @Override
    public void run(Reader in) throws IOException
    {
        while (readLetter(in) != -1);
    }

    public int readLetter(Reader in) throws IOException
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read()) != -1)
        {
            if (Character.isLetter(read))
                break;
        }
        return read;
    }
}

public class PerformanceTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String filePath = "/path/to/file.txt";

        Test[] tests = new Test[] { new WrapInFilterTest(), new RawReaderTest() };

        for (Test test : tests)
        {
            Reader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            System.out.println(test.timeRun(r) + "ns");
        }
    }
}
```

In general, I've found that the custom filter approach can be as much as 3x slower than straight up reading from the buffered reader. However, it seems dependent on the file content. For example, if a file contains strictly letters, I've found that the custom filter approach actually performs marginally faster! What's going on?

Comment: That's the problem.  You basically **need** to read from a `BufferedReader` or Java is doing an OS call per character.  Just wrap the raw stream in a `BufferedReader`, then continue to wrap it in whatever else you need.

Comment: I would guess it's because for the first read (using WrapInFilterTest) of `/path/to/file.txt` it's not yet in the filesystem cache, whereas for the second read (using RawReaderTest) it is. **1)** Change the order of the classes to compare the results, **2)** rerun the test several times, each class order, **3)** don't do any performance test like this, have a look at [intorduction to JMH](http://java-performance.info/jmh/)